# Get the remaining items in Select element Datalist

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

Say you have a datalist, like so:

```js
function validate() {
  let items = document.getElementById("zip").magicalMethodThatReturnsDatalistOptions();
  console.log("Remaining items: " + items.join(", ");
  }
```

```html
<body> <input id="zip" list="zipcodes" name="zip" oninput="validate()"> <datalist id="zipcodes"> <option value=11011> <option value=11342> <option value=12121> <option value=15453> <option value=10001> </datalist> </body>
```

And you want to access the remaining eligible autocomplete items as the user types, something like this:

For example, with the list above, if the user types in "11" the console will log:

> Remaining items: 11011, 11342

Is there a simple way to do this?

Now, I could write the oninput function to compare the current value with an array of options - but I'm hoping to just access this data directly since it's obviously already being done.  Surely somewhere there's an array that contains this information.

Comment: there is no builtin method for that

Comment: @Ethicist You can still come up with a solution, I posted one if you would like to review it.

Answer (score 1):

I coded this solution to get your option element's data add them to an array then loop through them and see if they include or don't include things wich other items have (explained in code) then logging remaimng items.

```js
let optionValues = document.getElementById("zipcodes").children;
let optionsRemaining = []; //Getting all options
for (let i = 0; i < optionValues.length; i++) {
  let x = optionValues[i].getAttribute("value"); //Getting options value "1101, etc"
  optionsRemaining.push(x); //Putting them into an array
}
console.log(optionsRemaining); //Logging them

//function to check
function validate() { 
  //Using a for loop to check through the whole array and return
  for (let i = 0; i < optionsRemaining.length; i++) {
    //Getting inputs value
    let itemStringValue = document.getElementById("zip").value;
    //Checking if input value includes what other things don't or do.
    if (optionsRemaining[i].includes(itemStringValue)) {
      //logging remaining data that can be selected.
      console.log("Remained: " + optionsRemaining[i]);
    }
  }
  //A divider so console is clean (Its bad without)
  console.log("---------------");
}
```

```html
<body> <input id="zip" list="zipcodes" name="zip" oninput="validate()"> <datalist id="zipcodes"> <option value="Thing1"> <option value="Thing2"> <option value="Thing3">  </datalist> </body>
```

Upvote if this helps :)

Edit: You can add as many options tags as you want and this will work with no added or extra code.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I'm specifically looking for a native way to access the values - it appears it's just not possible.

Comment: @JosephMassaro Yes it is not possible. The answer I have given can be shortened a little, following what you're looking for. I hope you can still integrate this though.